# How to integrate GTMOAuth with RestKit on iOS?

Tags: ios, oauth, restkit

I want to use GTMOAuth as the OAuth1 framework to log in to various services (Google, Dropbox, Twitter, etc.), and then to use RestKit for the actual REST communication. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proceed with using GTMOAuth as usual to get the access token. When you are there (and before using RKClient), initialize RKClient's OAuth1 properties like this (this will retrieve the account info from Dropbox):

```
- (void)doAnAuthenticatedAPIFetch {
    RKClient* client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"https://api.dropbox.com/1"]; 
    client.OAuth1AccessToken = mAuth.accessToken;
    client.OAuth1AccessTokenSecret = mAuth.tokenSecret;
    client.OAuth1ConsumerKey = mAuth.consumerKey;
    client.OAuth1ConsumerSecret = mAuth.privateKey;
    client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeOAuth1;

    [client get:@"/account/info" delegate:self];
}
```

It is important to initialize these values *before* using the RKClient for any other purpose (so that this will become the singleton sharedClient and that all communications are properly authorized).

Comment: There is no access token and access token secret for 2 legged OAuth authentication. In such cases if I set those parameters to nil, then will my requests be successful?